# pandas dataframe groupby and convert to json

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I know this kind of questions have been asked several times but I wish someone could help me with my problem.

The dataframe I've created is like below:

```
media = [
    {"date": "20231101", "media": "youtube", "view_count": 3, "url": "http://blah.com/a"},
    {"date": "20231101", "media": "facebook", "view_count": 3, "url": "http://blah.com/b"},
    {"date": "20231101", "media": "youtube", "view_count": 31, "url": "http://blah.com/c"},
    {"date": "20231101", "media": "instagram", "view_count": 6, "url": "http://blah.com/d"},
    {"date": "20231102", "media": "youtube", "view_count": 7, "url": "http://blah.com/e"},
    {"date": "20231103", "media": "facebook", "view_count": 12, "url": "http://blah.com/f"},
    {"date": "20231103", "media": "youtube", "view_count": 4, "url": "http://blah.com/g"},
    {"date": "20231104", "media": "youtube", "view_count": 5, "url": "http://blah.com/h"},
    {"date": "20231104", "media": "facebook", "view_count": 91, "url": "http://blah.com/i"},
    {"date": "20231104", "media": "facebook", "view_count": 2, "url": "http://blah.com/j"},
    {"date": "20231104", "media": "youtube", "view_count": 0, "url": "http://blah.com/k"},
    {"date": "20231105", "media": "instagram", "view_count": 1, "url": "http://blah.com/l"}
]
```

That I wish to do first groupby with 'date' and do second groupby with 'media', return results in json/dictionary format.

The desired format is like this:

```
{
    "20231101": {
        "youtube": [{"view_count": 3,"url": "http://blah.com/a"}, {"view_count": 31, "url": "http://blah.com/c"}],
        "facebook": [{"view_count": 3, "url": "http://blah.com/b"}],
        "instagram": [{"view_count": 6, "url": "http://blah.com/d"}]
    },
    "20231102": {
        "youtube": [{"view_count": 7, "url": "http://blah.com/e"}]
    },
    "20231103": {
        "youtube": [{"view_count": 4, "url": "http://blah.com/g"}],
        "facebook": [{"view_count": 12, "url": "http://blah.com/f"}]
    },
    "20231104": {
        "youtube": [{"view_count": 5, "url": "http://blah.com/h"}, {"view_count": 0, "url": "http://blah.com/k"}],
        "facebook": [{"view_count": 91, "url": "http://blah.com/i"}, {"view_count": 2, "url": "http://blah.com/j"}]
    },
    "20231105": {
        "instagram": [{"view_count": 0, "url": "http://blah.com/k"}]    
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(media)
rst = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x : x.groupby('media')['view_count', 'url'].agg(list)).to_dict()
```

But what I got is:

```
{
    'view_count': {
        ('20231101', 'facebook'): [3], 
        ('20231101', 'instagram'): [6], 
        ('20231101', 'youtube'): [3, 31], 
        ('20231102', 'youtube'): [7], 
        ('20231103', 'facebook'): [12], 
        ('20231103', 'youtube'): [4], 
        ('20231104', 'facebook'): [91, 2], 
        ('20231104', 'youtube'): [5, 0], 
        ('20231105', 'instagram'): [1]
    }, 
    'url': {
        ('20231101', 'facebook'): ['http://blah.com/b'], 
        ('20231101', 'instagram'): ['http://blah.com/d'], 
        ('20231101', 'youtube'): ['http://blah.com/a', 'http://blah.com/c'], 
        ('20231102', 'youtube'): ['http://blah.com/e'], 
        ('20231103', 'facebook'): ['http://blah.com/f'], 
        ('20231103', 'youtube'): ['http://blah.com/g'], 
        ('20231104', 'facebook'): ['http://blah.com/i', 'http://blah.com/j'], 
        ('20231104', 'youtube'): ['http://blah.com/h', 'http://blah.com/k'], 
        ('20231105', 'instagram'): ['http://blah.com/l']
    }
}
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Use nested dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and parameter `records`:

```
out = {k:{k1: v1[['view_count','url']].to_dict('records')
       for k1, v1 in v.groupby('media', sort=False)}
       for k, v in df.groupby('date', sort=False)}

print (out)

{
    "20231101": {
        "youtube": [
            {"view_count": 3, "url": "http://blah.com/a"},
            {"view_count": 31, "url": "http://blah.com/c"},
        ],
        "facebook": [{"view_count": 3, "url": "http://blah.com/b"}],
        "instagram": [{"view_count": 6, "url": "http://blah.com/d"}],
    },
    "20231102": {"youtube": [{"view_count": 7, "url": "http://blah.com/e"}]},
    "20231103": {
        "facebook": [{"view_count": 12, "url": "http://blah.com/f"}],
        "youtube": [{"view_count": 4, "url": "http://blah.com/g"}],
    },
    "20231104": {
        "youtube": [
            {"view_count": 5, "url": "http://blah.com/h"},
            {"view_count": 0, "url": "http://blah.com/k"},
        ],
        "facebook": [
            {"view_count": 91, "url": "http://blah.com/i"},
            {"view_count": 2, "url": "http://blah.com/j"},
        ],
    },
    "20231105": {"instagram": [{"view_count": 1, "url": "http://blah.com/l"}]},
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I should have used loops.

Comment: @Chan - You are welcome. Yop, here loops are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the combinations of `date`/`media` in a single [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and assign the data using a simple for loop with help of [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) + [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = {}

for (date, media), g in df.groupby(['date', 'media']):
    out.setdefault(date, {})[media] = g[['view_count', 'url']].to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
{'20231101': {'facebook': [{'view_count': 3, 'url': 'http://blah.com/b'}],
  'instagram': [{'view_count': 6, 'url': 'http://blah.com/d'}],
  'youtube': [{'view_count': 3, 'url': 'http://blah.com/a'},
   {'view_count': 31, 'url': 'http://blah.com/c'}]},
 '20231102': {'youtube': [{'view_count': 7, 'url': 'http://blah.com/e'}]},
 '20231103': {'facebook': [{'view_count': 12, 'url': 'http://blah.com/f'}],
  'youtube': [{'view_count': 4, 'url': 'http://blah.com/g'}]},
 '20231104': {'facebook': [{'view_count': 91, 'url': 'http://blah.com/i'},
   {'view_count': 2, 'url': 'http://blah.com/j'}],
  'youtube': [{'view_count': 5, 'url': 'http://blah.com/h'},
   {'view_count': 0, 'url': 'http://blah.com/k'}]},
 '20231105': {'instagram': [{'view_count': 1, 'url': 'http://blah.com/l'}]}}
```

Comment: @Chan you're welcome, if you test it in real condition, let me know how it scales!